# Is this a bad hack? Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some code that works, but just feels like a bad idea. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

**The Problem (You could honestly probably skip this and go to the code)**

I have a bluetooth LE app that occasionally needs to write characteristics as fast as possible to multiple BLE devices (The app is a controller for a smart lamp). My current set up for BLE communication is to use a `BluetoothContorller` custom singleton which handles all communication, and `Lamp` objects which ask the controller to write to the lamps and hand off their `BluetoothGatt` and `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` to the controller.

**The Solution**

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (control != null) {
                            synchronized (BluetoothController.this) {
                                Logger.d("BluetoothController", "Waiting......");

                                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                                    if(isWaiting)
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(10);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    else
                                        break;
                                }
                                isWaiting = true;

                                Logger.d("BluetoothController", "Done waiting.");
                            }

                        control.setValue(message);
                        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(control);
                    }
                }
            });
```

And inside my gatt callback:

```
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);

        if(isWaiting){
            isWaiting = false;
        }
    }
```

Now, this code works but all my experience as a programmer tells me that this code will cause me a lot of pain and surely there is a better.

**EDIT: New Code using Handler.Callback and Messages**

I've changed my code to do the waiting in the handle message callback, using Thread.wait() and notify(), but It seems like the messages are getting backed up in the queue, and the last one to execute still seems kind of random.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();

    handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            synchronized (BluetoothController.this) {
                if (shouldWait) {
                    isWaiting = true;
                    try {
                        BluetoothController.this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    isWaiting = false;
                }
                shouldWait = true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    Looper.loop();
}
```

Comment: I agree - polling is rarely a good idea, except perhaps in embedded systems.  Rather than Thread.sleep you should use Thread.wait(timeout) and notify() to interrupt it.  I don't have enough code to be able to provide a full implementation - the trick will be you need a reference to your waiting thread in the callback

Comment: Well...I tried using `Thread.wait()` before, as that seemed like the right way to use it, but it didn't work. I just tried implementing it again and it works just as well as my solution. I guess that's just how it goes sometimes. Submit this as an answer so you can get that sweet, juicy reputation. mmmmm

Comment: One problem I'm encountering with this solution...the last request sent after trying to send a bunch is pretty much random, not necessarily the last request I tried to send.

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the full structure, but I see that you use both control and message from outside of your `Runnable` so there is the possibility of non-threadsafe operations causing you problems.  Can you refactor so that you use a queue, with a single Runnable that wait()s if the queue is empty and is notify()ed when something is added to the queue.  It can then pull the message from the queue and process it, minimising the use of variables from outside the thread (you will need to synchronize on the queue data structure)

Comment: Check out the edit; I think I understand what you're saying, but I don't think what I put into the edit is exactly what you're saying. Is there some way for me actually control when/how the messages are popped off the queue?